# Generic approach to fetch and insert data in postgres with java spring boot

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot

Let's say - we have an entity class - User.

```
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
public class User {
  private UUID id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String dateOfBirth;
}
```

Our main purpose to copy data from another DB to our DB.
At first, we have to fetch data from another DB with a raw query

> "select first_name, last_name from user"

which gives us UserList.

> // some business logic

Then, we have to write a raw query to copy-

> "Insert into user (id, first_name, last_name) values (?,?,?,?)";

Now we have to iterate the UserList and use the PreparedStatement for storing data, like that :-

```
for(User user:userList){
preparedStatement.setObject(1,UUID);
preparedStatement.setObject(2,user.firstName());
preparedStatement.setObject(3,user.lastName());
preparedStatement.execute();
}
```

We can assume that the fields of the entity class will be similar to the user table columns in our DB and other DB from which we are copying.
Now, we've to write thousands of lines of code for our hundreds of entities. Can you give me some idea of simplifying this process? Like using Generics or something else?

I'm thinking about applying reflection in the entity class with generics. At first, I'll get the field names from T, creates the string, applying the preparedStatement with reflection api invoking the setObject method every time. Can you suggest to me any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ORM for that. e.g. JpaCrudRepositories allow you to do all that without all the manual mapping. This is pretty much the bread and butter of ORMs.

Because of the @Entity annotation I would assume that you are already using JPA...

Comment: Actually, we need to do a 'raw query with joining' for some complex business logic. That's why we can't do it with JPA.